# Best way to keep equal margins CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on a responsive grid and I'm trying to keep the margins the same on all four sides of the **main div** at each resolution. I've put margin 0 auto on the main div which keeps it equal on the right and the left but what about the top and bottom?

```
<div id = "wrapper">
<header id = "header"> <p> this is the header</p></header>
<div id = "main">
    <div id = "" class = "col col3">
        <div class = "img-col"><img src = "images/image.png"></div>
        <div class = "text-col">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vel eros libero. Fusce id semper orci. Morbi      imperdiet sit amet elit vel consectetur. Nam suscipit sem blandit est consectetur iaculis. Vestibulum sed dolor elementum, viverra sapien id, sollicitudin nibh. Integer quis venenatis ligula.Nam suscipit sem blandit est consectetur iaculis.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id = "" class = "col col1">
        <div class = "img-col"><img src = "images/image.png"></div>
        <div class = "text-col">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vel eros libero. Fusce id semper orci. Morbi imperdiet sit amet elit vel consectetur. Nam suscipit sem blandit est consectetur iaculis.</p> 
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vel eros libero.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,. </p>
    </div>
    </div> 

</div>
```

```
#main { 
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.col { 
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0px 1% 1.6%;
    background-color:#FF0000;   
}
```

Comment: Which exactly is the "content" here..? what about the size of wrap, header etc.. is this the whole css..?

Comment: Sorry to clear this up the content is the main div so underneath the header I want the margin to be the same as on the sides and underneath the main div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** after clarification.

If you need the **same margin on all four sides** (top/bottom/left/right) around the `#main` div, you will have to :

1. clearfix the floated content so that it doesn't overflow the bottom margin set on `#main`, you can use a pseudo element `:after` with `clear:both;` (see demo)
2. set `margin:10%;` on the `#main` div. Ass percent margins are calculated according to the containers width, all fourt margins will have the same value.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/QT9FH/3/)** (with some additional styling so you can see the margins)

and here is a screen shot that shows that the value of margin is the same for the four sides :

[image: same margin on all four sides]

---

**Original answer :**

Percent margins are calculated according to the containers width so if you set `margin:1%;` on `.col` the margins will be the same on the top, right, bottom and left.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/QT9FH/)

Comment: You're demo isn't centering the content vertically for all resolutions as far as i can see...

Comment: @TJ the OP states : *"I'm trying to keep the margins the same on all four sides"* and doesn't speak of vertical alignment. My answer provides a solution for that

Comment: "I've put margin 0 auto on the main div which keeps it equal on the right and the left but what about the top and bottom" it is pretty obvious that op is trying to center align the content with unknown height...

Comment: Yes I'm trying to keep the same margin size from mobile to large screens

Comment: @user3541612 are you trying to have the same margin value on all four sides or do you want to center `#main` horizontaly and verticaly?

Comment: user3541612 please clarify the above question because your question asks for the same margin on all four side whereas @TJ understood that you need to verticaly and horizontaly center `#main` div. If so, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: I'd be interested in either solution. But my original question is to keep equal margins on all four sides not necessarily centered. I'm struggling to get your solution to work. I have my cols side by side so that may be why?

Comment: yes thanks. So I can't have a width on the main div?

Comment: @user3541612 yes you can but you must be carefull that `left-margin + right-margin + width = 100%` otherwise it will overflow. see here : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/QT9FH/5/